# C# foreach doesn't modify properties of elements when iterating over collection created by linq .Select()

Tags: c#, linq

this Nunit test does not pass (and I expected it to).

```
class ReferenceObject
{
    public bool Flag { get; set; }
}

[Test]
public void CSharpWhyYouNoWork()
{
    //given
    var someRange = Enumerable.Range(0, 3);

    var selectedEnumerable = someRange.Select(p => new ReferenceObject());

    //when
    foreach (var foreachIterationVariable in selectedEnumerable)
    {
        foreachIterationVariable.Flag = true;
    }

    //then
    Assert.That(selectedEnumerable.All(p => p.Flag));
}
```

I thought foreach iteration variable is passed by reference, so I expected it to modify the objects of the collection.

Funnily, if I used a list, like that:

```
someRange.Select(...).ToList();
```

then everything works as expected and the test passes - I'd like to know why that happens...

Comment: `selectedEnumerable` is not a collection, `ToList` creates a new list, it materializes the deferred executed query.

Comment: what does Select do, then? I thought it creates an IEnumerable and would let me change the objects..

Comment: modifying the list object inside the foreach should throw error.

Comment: @Mateusz; it just tells .NET what to do when [`GetEnumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator(v=vs.110).aspx) is called. But at this point it is not called. It's like a sequence plan that you define. Everytime you f.e. use `foreach` or `ToList` on `selectedEnumerable` it is executed and it creates new `ReferenceObject` everytime.

Comment: *modifying the list object inside the foreach should throw error* No, it shouldn't. He isn't adding or removing any elements.

Comment: cool, thanks, yeah, so Select works more like a promise and defers materialization of data till you want to do anything, now I get it, thanks, guys :D

Comment: It's like a sql query that you define. The definition of the sql query doesn't execute it. You could execute it multiple times with different results (because the database changed meanwhile). If you execute it and store it in a variable(f.e. `List<ReferenceObject> list=selectedEnumerable.ToList();`) you persist that result.

Comment: @MateuszTarnaski Please select an answer so it doesn't show up in unanswered questions :)

Answer (score 6):

> I'd like to know why that happens

Because `Select` returns an *iterator*, not a list or an array, which is lazily evaluated. You iterate that iterator once during `foreach`, and then *another time* during `Enumerable.All`. This causes **the query to be executed twice**, yielding an `IEnumerable<T>` each time.

When you materialize the query using `ToList` you cause a list to be created once, and then you iterate that *same list* twice, which yields the desired effect in your `Assert`.

Answer (score 4):

You are never creating a list (or any kind of materialized collection), just an enumeration. The `foreach` created a new enumeration all the way from `Enumerable.Range()` and your final check also uses a new enumeration all the way from `Enumerable.Range()`.

You must create a collection or something persistent to be sure to modify the same elements.

An enumeration can be a materialized collection, but it doesn't have to be.

And a clarification of terms as I see them;

> an `enumeration` is `an iteration over a number of objects`

which gives;

> enumerations are iterations but not all iterations are enumerations